# Incorrectly positioned jQuery Mobile header elements in Chrome v26 when two headers are used in a single page

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I'm having a layout issue with my jQuery-Mobile site which only began occurring after updating Google Chrome to version 26. The basic layout of my page is as follows: two panes, "desktopSideBar" and "desktopContentPane", each containing their own header.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" position="fixed">
    <div id="desktopSideBar">
        <div id="mobile_navigation_content">
            <div class="ui-bar-a ui-header" data-position="inline" id="navigationHeader">
                <a class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b"></a>
                <h4>First Header</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="desktopContentPane">
        <div class="ui-bar-a ui-header" data-position="inline" id="contentToolbar">
            <a class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="arrow-l" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Hide</a>
            <h4>Second header</h4>
            <a class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, this type of thing isn't exactly built-in to the jQM framework, so I had to add some javascript code for properly positioning and resizing the panes and their headers.

[This fiddle shows a simplified version of my page.](http://jsfiddle.net/aUk9R/7/)

The issue is in the header on the right, where the header's title and rightmost button are stacked on its left side. Opening the fiddle in Firefox or IE will show the desired layout.

The strange thing is, Chrome still seems to know where the elements *should* be. Clicking on the button with the gear icon will instantly make it go to the right, and if you right-click the header and choose "Inspect element", you can make the whole header bar fix itself by unchecking and checking some of the css styles on the `<div class="ui-header">` tag.

What I'm looking for is firstly, any idea what might have changed in Chrome v.26 which could cause this, as this would help me get to the root of the problem.

I also wouldn't mind if someone actually knows what the root of the problem is, as currently my workaround is to add this into the resizing code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#contentToolbar").removeClass("ui-header").find("h4").css("text-align", "left");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#contentToolbar").addClass("ui-header").find("h4").css("text-align", "center");
    }, 5);
}, 500);
```

... which causes a noticeable flicker when the elements are repositioned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is an example on ui-grid.

> Note: Tested on Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Phmjc/)**

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
 <div class="ui-block-a">
  <div data-role=header data-theme=b>
   <a href=# data-role=button data-icon=back data-iconpos=notext>g</a>
   <h6>header</h6>
   <a href=# data-role=button data-icon=gear data-iconpos=notext>g</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role=content>contents</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-block-b">
 <div data-role=header data-theme=e>
  <a href=# data-role=button data-icon=arrow-l data-iconpos=notext>g</a>
  <h6>header</h6>
  <a href=# data-role=button data-icon=star data-iconpos=notext>g</a>
 </div>
 <div data-role=content>contents</div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-block-b {
 width: 25% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
}
.ui-block-a {
 width: 75% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
 border-right: solid 1px #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Actually I had deliberately left out the data-role="content" and "header" attributes in order to force the header to be fixed without overlaying the content. I also needed the two panes to be aligned horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: @Alejo sorry, I just noticed your fiddle. You want to align them vertically. In this case, I would recommend using ui-grids, it could be easier to manipulate.

Comment: I don't have time to incorporate this right now, but I'll mark it as the answer since it solves the problem.